# Angular same route but different layout depending on logged in state

Tags: angular

I currently have several routes, divided in two different LayoutComponents. The MainLayoutComponent contains all pages that logged in users can see (With a NavBar etc).
The LoginLayoutComponent does not have the NavBar:

```
      {
    path: '', component: MainLayoutComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'loggedin', component: HomeComponent },
      ...
      { path: 'stuff', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/stuff/stuff.module').then(m => m.StuffModule)}
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '', component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: UserLoginComponent },
      { path: 'loggedout', redirectTo: '/login' },
    ]
  },
```

I now want to share a page that is currently visible for logged in users also for anonymous users. But the anonymous users should not see the NavBar, therefore I want to use another LayoutComponent.
But how do I redirect the users to the page in the sub module (StuffModule) but with different Layouts depending on their authentication state?

Currently if unauthenticated users open /stuff/page they get forwarded to login page.
If I move the `{ path: 'stuff', loadChildren: ...` line to the LoginLayoutComponent it works for them, but the logged in users does not have the NavBar anymore.

It is also important that it is the same path for both cases (These pages might be shared publicly or just within the community. The shared link should work for both.).

Comment: It's better to have 2 different route for different user

Comment: Not in this case: A user can share a link to his page, and define whether it should be viewable only by other users or for unauthenticated users as well. It would not make sense to present two links and ask the customer: "Use this for other users and this for non-users".

Comment: then you just have an option of hide and show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not the most beautiful solution but I found a way to solve it:

I've created a component that is publicly accessible with a normally routed URL, let's say /share/public/myId.
In this component I check whether there is a successfully authenticated session available:

- If yes, forward to the internal page (e.g. /share/internal/myId) and show the document as usual with the NavBar etc.
- If no, stay on the page and load the document without the stuff that auth'ed users would have.

This way, users can always share the same link (/share/public/myId) and forward it to other users or non-users, just how they want.

Comment: You can use *ngIf to show/hide components on a page.  <NavBar *ngIf="authenticated"></NavBar >

Comment: Sure, I know. But as described below I could then not use the Guard as before and have to put multiple ngIf's in, which wouldn't be a good solution as well.